# Angular - passing variable to script in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular

I'm trying to send the variable array 'series' to the script in HTML.
Is there any way?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Map';

    series: any[];

    constructor() {

       this.series=[["RUS",50],["CAN",88],["CHE",21],["IND",43],
        ["GRL",21],["MEX",19],["FRA",60],["MAC",4],]
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>

  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let country of series">
      {{ country }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Inside **index.html**

```
...
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/1.6.9/topojson.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datamaps/0.5.8/datamaps.all.js"></script>

<script>
    // -----------------------Need VARIABLES HERE-----------------------
    var series = [
        ["RUS",50],["CAN",88],["CHE",21],["IND",43],
        ["GRL",21],["MEX",19],["FRA",60],["MAC",4],];


    // Datamaps expect data in format:
    // { "USA": { "fillColor": "#42a844", numberOfWhatever: 75},
    //   "FRA": { "fillColor": "#8dc386", numberOfWhatever: 43 } }
    var dataset = {};

  ...
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sk1gaf

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by injecting `document` into your component and assign it a variable like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8xkz1

I am sure you have your reasons but I highly discourage from doing this, use angular components for your logic instead of index.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to do this as i am getting the data from json api and i am just passing it to the view.

Comment: Doesn't sound like something you couldn't do using angular the way it is intended to. (Using components)

Comment: Please point me the direction, I am taking country names and no.of case from https://disease.sh/v2/continents and trying to show it on map